# Accessing Parameter store secret with amplify.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I have an Amplify nextjs project and im attempting to follow the docs and call a parameter store secret in my amplify.yml. I need this to configure my nextauth implementation. It seems to be failing post build.

#### AWS Parameter Store secret

`/amplify/{my_amplify_id}/development/NEXTAUTH_SECRET`

My amplify id has been obfuscated here

#### amplify.yml

```yaml
    build:
      commands:
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=${NEXTAUTH_SECRET}" >> .env
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=${NEXTAUTH_URL}" >> .env
        - npm run build
```

#### amplify service role permissions

```
Policy name 
Type
Attached entities
AdministratorAccess-Amplify AWS managed 2
AmplifySSRLoggingPolicy-{my_amplify_id} Customer managed    1
AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess AWS managed 1
AWSCodeCommitFullAccess AWS managed 1
SecretsManagerReadWrite AWS managed
```

#### error

```
[next-auth][error][NO_SECRET]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret Please define a `secret` in production. MissingSecret [MissingSecretError]: Please define a `secret` in production.
at t.assertConfig (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/810.js:6:114110)
at AuthHandler (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/810.js:6:107240)
at async getServerSession (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/810.js:30:19204)
```

logs incomplete Cloudwatch is being weird

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#environment-secrets
[2] https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2466

Comment: Read: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret

Comment: Not sure what your suggesting? The link is for next auth which does not seem to be at fault here.

Comment: Your error literally has a link to it?

Comment: Correct? There isnt a warning locally when building + starting or starting dev. It seems that the issue is around exposing the env vars as this does not happen when using a `.env` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places that can cause this approach to fail so ive outlined each of the steps ive worked out to get this working.

### amplify service permissions

Permissions on the amplify service role MUST be amended to even be accessed. This will cause calls to $secret to fail if not implemented.

```
AdministratorAccess-Amplify
AmplifySSRLoggingPolicy-mydevid
AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess
AWSCodeCommitFullAccess
SecretsManagerReadWrite
```

### accessing SSM variables from amplify

```yaml
 commands:
        - yum install jq -y
        # secrets
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$(echo $secrets | jq -r '.NEXTAUTH_SECRET')" >> .env
        - echo "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=$(echo $secrets | jq -r '.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')" >> .env
        # share amplify env vars
        - echo "DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL" >> .env
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env
```

You MUST extract the values from a json string called $secrets.

$secrets will look something like this in my case, with your SSM variable name being the key and its value being the value. `{"NEXTAUTH_SECRET":"theKeyIsHere"}`

The easiest way to access these is by first using yum to get the jq tool.

You can then use jq to access the value only for a given key like and append it to your `.env` as shown here. `echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$(echo $secrets | jq -r '.NEXTAUTH_SECRET')" >> .env`

### configure secrets

This one is easy to miss, you have to declare your branch within the secret setup. So accessing `/amplify/applicationid/development/GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` in a branch called prod is not possible and will fail silently. You have to configure these per branch.

### share amplify env vars

This one is in the documentation but not obvious. You also have to share the non secret variables in the yml as shown above. This manifested as a config error and was hard to find. It was resolved with the following line `echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env`

Comment: are you doing this on the preBuild or build phase? also are you using Amazon Linux:2023 image?

Comment: Which bit do you need clarification on? I can update the answer I just don't know which section you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above solution in case anybody else is struggling with installing jq and you have a secret that is not named according to docs you can read directly from secrets manager like so

```
- echo "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id NEXTAUTH_SECRET --query SecretString --output text)" >> .env
```

This will work if you have a plain text secret for a given secret id instead of multiple key/value pairs.